# how to find the words that are likely to follow the single word in large string in python .?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7

```
str1=""”Python is a widely used high-level programming language for general-purpose programming, created by Guido van Rossum and first released in 1991. An interpreted language, Python has a design philosophy which emphasizes code readability (notably using whitespace indentation to delimit code blocks rather than curly braces or keywords), and a syntax which allows programmers to express concepts in fewer lines of code than possible in languages such as C++ or Java. The language provides constructs intended to enable writing clear programs on both a small and large scale .Python features a dynamic type system and automatic memory management and supports multiple programming paradigms, including object-oriented, imperative, functional programming, and procedural styles. It has a large and comprehensive standard library. Python interpreters are available for many operating systems, allowing Python code to run on a wide variety of systems. CPython, the reference implementation of Python, is open source software and has a community-based development model, as do nearly all of its variant implementations. CPython is managed by the non-profit Python Software Foundation."""..
```

output should be :

```
python : [is, has, features, interpreters, code, Software
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a regex to look for words that follow the word python, for example

```
>>> import re
>>> re.findall(r'Python (\w+)', s)
['is', 'has', 'features', 'interpreters', 'code', 'is', 'Software']
```

Since this list may contain duplicates, you could create a `set` if you want a collection of unique words

```
>>> set(re.findall(r'Python (\w+)', s))
{'Software', 'is', 'has', 'interpreters', 'code', 'features'}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a generator for this:

```
def yielder(x, value='Python'):
    match = False
    for word in x.split():
        if match == True:
            yield word
            match = False
        if word == value:
            match = True

res = list(yielder(str1))

['is', 'has', 'interpreters', 'code', 'Software']
```

The benefit of this method is that it is lazy *after splitting*. For long strings, you can extract results as you iterate.

To learn more, look up the following:

- Generators: how does `yield` statement work
- Split strings: how does `str.split` work